# My program doesn't respond to my keystroke judgments?

Tags: python

I am new to python, trying to write some small games using pygame,
A difficulty I am currently encountering is:
When my program is running, it always skips or does not respond to where I should enter judgment.
I have tried many methods, inquired a lot of information, and used sleep(), delay(), input(), game_stop(), etc.
Still can't solve my problem
Please God help me!
My code is roughly as follows:

```
import sys,random,math,pygame
import time
from pygame.locals import *

def print_text(font, x, y, text, color = (100,100,100)):
    imgText = font.render(text, True, color)
    window.blit(imgText, (x,y))
    
pygame.init()


window = pygame.display.set_mode((1400,700))
pygame.display.set_caption('第一關')
window.fill((120,120,120))
font = pygame.font.Font('aa.ttf',50)

main = pygame.image.load("main.png").convert_alpha()
wolf = pygame.image.load("wolf.png").convert_alpha()

text0 = font.render('請幫助兔子們驅趕野狼',True,(255,255,255))
window.blit(text0,(550,150))

bx1,by1,bw,bh = 625,550,150,100
pygame.draw.rect(window,(0,255,0),(bx1,by1,bw,bh))
text1 = font.render('確定',True,(255,255,255))
tw1,th1 = text1.get_size()
tx1 = bx1 + bw/2 - tw1/2
ty1 = by1 + bh/2 - th1/2
window.blit(text1,(tx1,ty1))
pygame.display.flip()

play01 = False

green = 0 , 255 , 0


wolflife = 100
gameround = 1
circle_size = 200

while True:
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.QUIT 
            
    
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mx,my = event.pos
            if bx1 <= mx <= bx1 + bw and by1 <= my <= by1 + bh :
                pygame.draw.rect(window,(200,200,200),(bx1,by1,bw,bh))
                window.blit(text1,(tx1,ty1))
                pygame.display.update()
                play01 = True
                
    if play01 == True:
        window.fill((120,120,120))
        window.blit(main,(0,100))
        window.blit(wolf,(1000,100))
        while wolflife > 10:
            print("現在回合是",gameround,"\n")
            text2 = font.render('剩餘血量:',True,(255,255,255))
            window.blit(text2,(1100,600))
            print('剩餘血量:',wolflife)
#             window.blit(wolflife,(1200,600))
            pygame.draw.circle(window, green, (700,350), circle_size, 0)
            pygame.display.flip()
        
#             input()
#             time.sleep(5)
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    char = chr(event.key)
                    #使用了能量
                    if  char == 'a':
                        print("使用能量!對野狼造成傷害!")
                        wolflife -= 30
                        gameround += 1
                    else :
                        print("使用了錯誤能量!再試試看吧!")
                        gameround += 1

            if wolflife <= 10:
                window.fill((120,120,120))           
                text3 = font.render('恭喜你!',True,(255,255,255))
                text4 = font.render('你幫助兔子驅趕了野狼!',True,(255,255,255))
                window.blit(text3,(550,150))
                window.blit(text4,(500,250))
                pygame.draw.rect(window,(0,255,0),(bx1,by1,bw,bh))
                window.blit(text1,(tx1,ty1))
                pygame.display.flip()    
                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    mx,my = event.pos
                    if bx1 <= mx <= bx1 + bw and by1 <= my <= by1 + bh :
                        pygame.draw.rect(window,(200,200,200),(bx1,by1,bw,bh))
                        window.blit(text1,(tx1,ty1))
                        pygame.display.update()
                        pygame.QUIT
```

According to the above methods I have tried, the program execution results will have several situations:

1. The program enters an infinite loop and crashes
2. After entering the screen, it shows no response and then ends.

The result of the program execution I expected is that when I press the button a, the opponent's life value will drop until 10, and the wrong button will have to be re-entered.

And I hope that when the program is executed, it can stay for some time so that I can perform the action of 'clicking the button a', or let the program wait for me to make a 'clicking the button' to determine whether it is a.

```
    if play01 == True:
        window.fill((120,120,120))
        window.blit(main,(0,100))
        window.blit(wolf,(1000,100))
        while wolflife > 10:
            print("現在回合是",gameround,"\n")
            text2 = font.render('剩餘血量:',True,(255,255,255))
            window.blit(text2,(1100,600))
            print('剩餘血量:',wolflife)
#             window.blit(wolflife,(1200,600))
            pygame.draw.circle(window, green, (700,350), circle_size, 0)
            pygame.display.flip()
        
#             input()
#             time.sleep(5)
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    char = chr(event.key)
                    #使用了能量
                    if  char == 'a':
                        print("使用能量!對野狼造成傷害!")
                        wolflife -= 30
                        gameround += 1
                    else :
                        print("使用了錯誤能量!再試試看吧!")
                        gameround += 1
```

I think the problem may be with this part of the decision, maybe some part of my code is not good

Comment: Can you post a [mre] that only contains the problematic code?

Comment: Just from a quick glance, the `if` statements checking for `event.type` need to be indented to match the indentation of `if event.type == pygame.QUIT:` because they are meant to be part of the `for event in pygame.event.get():` loop.

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on how to debug your code.

Comment: This is also what bothers me. After I finish executing the program, it doesn't show an error, which makes me a little overwhelmed.